# Efficient ways to do a timer which updates every second in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I had a task to make a progress bar and a process duration timer along with it. So, not thinking twice I did this:

```
<div class="mainInfo">
    <div id="timer"><span id="elapsedText">0:00</span>/<span id="durationText">3:00</span></div>
    <div id="progressBar"><div id="progress" style="width:0;"></div></div>
</div>​
```

And the JS:

```
var time = 1000;
var duration = 180;

var $progress = $("#progress");
var $elapsedText = $("#elapsedText");

updateTime();

function updateTime() {
    var elapsed = time / 1000;
    $elapsedText.text(Math.floor(elapsed / 60) + ":" + Math.floor(elapsed % 60));
    $progress.css('width', (elapsed * 100 / duration) + "%");
    time = time + 1000;
    setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
}​
```

Time is actually retrieved from another variable - this ones for the demo (to illustrate that I actually have the value in miliseconds).

And it worked (not only on my PC), and still does, but the procmon shows a CPU spike on browser (chrome, ff) process when this cycle is running - 30-40% instead of regular 0,5%.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `"updateTime()"` => `updateTime`

Comment: Use `setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);`, do never pass a string to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)!

Comment: That was a stupid mistake, that I see, though I wouldn't say "never pass a string to setTimeout" since it could be used not only for one function call :)

Comment: @povilasp anonymous functions are always faster than running a compiler. Only ever pass a string if you feel `eval` would be the other option. That is, never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
setTimeout("updateTime()", 1000);
```

use

```
setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
```

The fact that you're invoking the compiler each second could really hurt performance. Passing a string to `setTimeout` is basically causing an `eval` within the `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard function for that: [SetInterval(function, delay_in_ms)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).

It calls a function in millisecond intervals.

Comment: Trailing `setTimeout` is pretty standard. Why do you think `setInterval` could be better?

Comment: Because it's more accurate. The execution of the body of setTimeout also takes time. When it takes, let's say, 25 milliseconds, and then you do another setTimeout(1000), it's only executed every 1025 ms.

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case. Often it's better to just say "and wait one second, then run again".

Answer (score 2):

There is a default for that, and that is `setInterval`.

Be careful, the function passed as the first argument to `setInterval` is always executed in global scope.

Number two, a progress bar is usually created along-side expensive processes. You are using it for display purposes only and forcing a delay, which I don't particularly find useful, but if you like the layout, I guess you can go for it.

The way you would usually use it is:

```
executeFirstPotentiallyExpensiveProcess();// this is a call to a big function.
// then update the value of the progress bar in percentage style.
executeSecondPotentiallyExpensiveFunction()// this is the second part of your process.
// then again update..
// repeat until you have 100%.
// Basically, you logically divide the expenses of your various executions
// into numerable bits, preferably equal to one another for your convenience,
// but you chunk your loading process or whatever type of process and increment
// the progress after each chunk is complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the function setInterval.

Comment: you could post this in the comment.

Comment: You're trying to answer a question by asking one yourself.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to post this in the comment. @BehnamEsmaili

Answer (score 1):

Your use of jQuery disturbs me...

```
var time = 1000;
var duration = 180;

var $progress = document.getElementById("progress");
var $elapsedText = document.getElementById("elapsedText");

var beginTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

updateTime();
setInterval(updateTime,1000);

function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = now-beginTimeStamp + time;
    $elapsedText.firstChild.nodeValue = Math.floor(elapsed / 60) + ":" + Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    $progress.style.width = (elapsed * 100 / duration) + "%";
}​
```

Maybe without jQuery your browser might run better ;)

Comment: Feel the need to explain my bad behaviour: the code was ripped apart from a bigger application which jquery is used a lot :)